# Overriding do_compile() functionality in bbappend

Tags: yocto, bitbake

I have a bb file with a do_compile function that I would like to override/replace without modiying the bb file. I want to completely change the content of do_compile, and have its 'new'  execution content in a bbappend file.

Is there a way to do this?

I tried a couple of things:

1. In the bbappend file I created a function do_compile(), this does not replace the original nor gets executed
2. In the bbappend file I created a function do_compile_append(), this seems to be never executed at all
3. In the bbappend file I created a function do_install_prepend(), this is executed. However, this is not ideal as the original do_compile is also executed.

Any help would be appreciated

Comment: `1.` should work, can you post your recipe and bbappend as well?

Comment: Can you verify that the bbappend is actually evaluated? bitbake-layers show-appends is your friend.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As @Nayfe commented, defining `do_compile()` in your `.bbappend` should work.

If your `do_compile()` function does not take effect, this may mean a few things:

1. It may mean that another layer has precedence over your layer. Check your layer's [`BBFILE_PRIORITY`](https://www.yoctoproject.org/docs/current/ref-manual/ref-manual.html#var-BBFILE_PRIORITY) variable. A tip is to run `bitbake-layers show-overlayed` and check your recipe for overlays.
2. In some cases, the `.bb` file may disable tasks completely using the `noexec` directive. For example `do_compile[noexec] = "1"` disables compilation entirely. This is intended for recipes installing scripts or configuration files mostly.
3. Your layer is not defined in `bblayers.conf`.